# Resize the imshow window in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to resize the window or equal to the figure showing inside the box. Is it possible in `Matlab`? As the figure is showing below.

[image]

Comment: `set(gca,'Unit','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1])` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this commands:

```
>> figure(1)
>> imshow('linkedin.jpg')
>> figure(2)
>> imshow('linkedin.jpg','Border','tight')
```

[image]